# Listing a few mathematical identities compactly

Tags: align, enumerate

[image: preview of current formatting]

Hello,

I want to list a few mathemical identitites compactly. Currently, I use the enumerate environment combined with align but that takes up way too much space. First of all, the linebreaks after the enumeration symbol (which I would also like to change to i, ii, iii, iv, etc) seems not necessary and just increases the size needlessly. I would also like to do it in a

```
a   b
  c
```

kind of way but I couldn't get that done without hardcoding the enumeration symbols.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} 
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{braket} 

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 

\newcommand{\an}{\hat{a}} 
\newcommand{\cre}{\hat{a}^\dagger} 

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item   \begin{align}
                \comm{\an}{\cre} \ket{n}    &= \an \cre \ket{n} - \cre \an \ket{n} \nonumber \\ 
                                                    &= \left( n + 1 \right) \ket{n} - n \ket{n} \nonumber \\ 
                                                    &= \ket{n} \nonumber \\ 
                \Rightarrow \comm{\an}{\cre}= 1
            \end{align}
    \item   \begin{align}
                \comm{\hat{N}}{\an} \ket{n}         &= \hat{N} \an \ket{n} - \an \hat{N} \ket{N} \nonumber \\ 
                                                    &= \left( n - 1 \right) \sqrt{n} \ket{n-1} - n \sqrt{n} \ket{n-1} \nonumber \\ 
                                                    &= - \sqrt{n} \ket{n-1} \nonumber \\ 
                                                    &= - \an \ket{n} \nonumber \\ 
                \Rightarrow \comm{\hat{N}}{\an}     &= - \an
            \end{align}
    \item   \begin{align}
                \comm{\hat{N}}{\cre} \ket{n}        &= \hat{N} \cre \ket{n} - \cre \hat{N} \ket{n} \nonumber \\ 
                                                    &= \left( n+1 \right) \sqrt{n+1} \ket{n+1} - n \sqrt{n+1} \ket{n+1} \nonumber \\ 
                                                    &= \sqrt{n+1} \ket{n+1} \nonumber \\ 
                                                    & \cre \ket{n} \nonumber \\ 
                \Rightarrow \comm{\hat{N}}{\cre}    &= \cre 
            \end{align}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Edit:

By using the aligned environment I get this:

[image: updated example by using the aligned environment]

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item   $\begin{aligned}[t]
                \comm{\an}{\cre} \ket{n}        &= \an \cre \ket{n} - \cre \an \ket{n} \\ 
                                                &= \left( n + 1 \right) \ket{n} - n \ket{n} \\ 
                                                &= \ket{n} \\ 
                \Rightarrow \comm{\an}{\cre}    &= 1
            \end{aligned}$ \label{one}
    \item   $\begin{aligned}[t] 
                \comm{\hat{N}}{\an} \ket{n}     &= \hat{N} \an \ket{n} - \an \hat{N} \ket{N}  \\ 
                                                &= \left( n - 1 \right) \sqrt{n} \ket{n-1} - n \sqrt{n} \ket{n-1} \\ 
                                                &= - \sqrt{n} \ket{n-1} \\ 
                                                &= - \an \ket{n} \\ 
                \Rightarrow \comm{\hat{N}}{\an} &= - \an
            \end{aligned}$
    \item   $\begin{aligned}[t]
                \comm{\hat{N}}{\cre} \ket{n}        &= \hat{N} \cre \ket{n} - \cre \hat{N} \ket{n} \\ 
                                                    &= \left( n+1 \right) \sqrt{n+1} \ket{n+1} - n \sqrt{n+1} \ket{n+1}\\ 
                                                    &= \sqrt{n+1} \ket{n+1} \\ 
                                                    & \cre \ket{n} \\ 
                \Rightarrow \comm{\hat{N}}{\cre}    &= \cre 
            \end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: why do you want numbers from `align` and from `enumerate` isn't that just confusing? Normally you would just have one or the other,

Comment: if you just had numbers from enumerate use `\item $\begin{aligned}[t]....$`

Comment: I don't really know why I used numbers from both. It looks a lot cleaner when using the aligned environment. You can see the result in the first post. I don't really know how to use \label and \ref when I only use the numbers from enumerate. If I put a \label after the aligned environment in the corresponding \item and reference it somewhere with \ref, the \ref just prints a "1". That seems a bit confusing. It would be nice if it printed whatever is used as the enumeration symbol but that might be confusing too. How would you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a solution with `tasks` package.

As Zarko suggested, with the option `t` of the `aligned` environment, you can also have the numbering at the top.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} 
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{braket} 

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 

\newcommand{\an}{\hat{a}} 
\newcommand{\cre}{\hat{a}^\dagger} 


\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{
    counter-format={tsk[r])},% lowcase roman number
    label-offset={0pt},% distance between label and item
    label-width={1.1em},%width of the item label
    item-indent={1.1em},% horizontal space available for both label and label-offset
    column-sep={0em},
    %debug=true
}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
    The \verb|tasks| package
    creates lists in columns counting horizontally rather than vertically.
    Here you can find the first \ref{eq:first} and the second \ref{eq:second} equations side by side, and the third \ref{eq:third} centered 
    with a \verb|minipage|. 
\begin{center}
    \footnotesize
    %\scriptsize% otherwise you go out of the page margins
\begin{tasks}(2)
    \task\label{eq:first}
    $\begin{aligned}
    \comm{\an}{\cre} \ket{n}    &= \an \cre \ket{n} - \cre \an \ket{n} \nonumber \\ 
    &= \left( n + 1 \right) \ket{n} - n \ket{n} \nonumber \\ 
    &= \ket{n} \nonumber \\ 
    \Rightarrow \comm{\an}{\cre} &= 1
    \end{aligned}$ 
    \task\label{eq:second}  
    $\begin{aligned}
        \comm{\hat{N}}{\an} \ket{n}         &= \hat{N} \an \ket{n} - \an \hat{N} \ket{N} \nonumber \\ 
        &= \left( n - 1 \right) \sqrt{n} \ket{n-1} - n \sqrt{n} \ket{n-1} \nonumber \\ 
        &= - \sqrt{n} \ket{n-1} \nonumber \\ 
        &= - \an \ket{n} \nonumber \\ 
        \Rightarrow \comm{\hat{N}}{\an}     &= - \an
    \end{aligned}$  
\end{tasks}
\begin{minipage}{.56\linewidth}%.56 to avoid overfull hbox
\begin{tasks}[resume=true]% resume=true to continue the enumeration from the previous task 
    \task\label{eq:third}
        $\begin{aligned}  
            \comm{\hat{N}}{\cre} \ket{n}        &= \hat{N} \cre \ket{n} - \cre \hat{N} \ket{n} \nonumber \\ 
            &= \left( n+1 \right) \sqrt{n+1} \ket{n+1} - n \sqrt{n+1} \ket{n+1} \nonumber \\ 
            &= \sqrt{n+1} \ket{n+1} \nonumber \\ 
            & \cre \ket{n} \nonumber \\ 
            \Rightarrow \comm{\hat{N}}{\cre}    &= \cre 
    \end{aligned}$
\end{tasks}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}


    Or with option \verb|t|, as Zarko suggested, with \ref{eq:zfirst}, \ref{eq:zsecond} and the third \ref{eq:zthird} at the top: 
\begin{center}
    \footnotesize
    %\scriptsize% otherwise you go out of the page margins
\begin{tasks}(2)
    \task\label{eq:zfirst}
    $\begin{aligned}[t]
    \comm{\an}{\cre} \ket{n}    &= \an \cre \ket{n} - \cre \an \ket{n} \nonumber \\ 
    &= \left( n + 1 \right) \ket{n} - n \ket{n} \nonumber \\ 
    &= \ket{n} \nonumber \\ 
    \Rightarrow \comm{\an}{\cre} &= 1
    \end{aligned}$ 
    \task\label{eq:zsecond}  
    $\begin{aligned}[t]
        \comm{\hat{N}}{\an} \ket{n}         &= \hat{N} \an \ket{n} - \an \hat{N} \ket{N} \nonumber \\ 
        &= \left( n - 1 \right) \sqrt{n} \ket{n-1} - n \sqrt{n} \ket{n-1} \nonumber \\ 
        &= - \sqrt{n} \ket{n-1} \nonumber \\ 
        &= - \an \ket{n} \nonumber \\ 
        \Rightarrow \comm{\hat{N}}{\an}     &= - \an
    \end{aligned}$  
\end{tasks}
\begin{minipage}{.56\linewidth}%.56 to avoid overfull hbox
\begin{tasks}[resume=true]% resume=true to continue the enumeration from the previous task 
    \task\label{eq:zthird}
        $\begin{aligned}[t]  
            \comm{\hat{N}}{\cre} \ket{n}        &= \hat{N} \cre \ket{n} - \cre \hat{N} \ket{n} \nonumber \\ 
            &= \left( n+1 \right) \sqrt{n+1} \ket{n+1} - n \sqrt{n+1} \ket{n+1} \nonumber \\ 
            &= \sqrt{n+1} \ket{n+1} \nonumber \\ 
            & \cre \ket{n} \nonumber \\ 
            \Rightarrow \comm{\hat{N}}{\cre}    &= \cre 
    \end{aligned}$
\end{tasks}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: to my taste the better rezult is obtained if you ad to `aligned` option `[t]`, for example `\task\label{eq:third} $\begin{aligned}[t] ... \end{aligned}`.

Comment: @Zarko Answer renewed, thanks! Since it is not very clear what the OP wants, I kept both solutions.